# How would I get user input in a sequence and then have the sequence determine the outcome? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Ok so I know the code below is messy, I'm just curious though. What I am trying to do is create a list of radio buttons, and then depending on the sequence the user inputs have a different outcome. I'm a nooby to javascript so I'm just curious how I'd do this. Currently I'm trying to make the code where if the user inputs the radio buttons 1, 2, 5. He moves on otherwise he has to restart. (text-based RPG)

```
  function defend() {

var node = document.getElementById("container");
node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "" + "</p>" +
"<center>" +
"<input class='radio1' type='radio'>" + "<input class='radio2' type='radio'>" + "<input class='radio3' type='radio'>" + "<input class='radio4' type='radio'>" + "<input class='radio5'      type='radio'>" + "<input class='radio6' type='radio'>"
+ "</center>" + "<center>" + "<div class='defend' onClick='sequence' id='buttons'>" + "<p>" + "Initiate" + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</center>";
var sequence = document.getElementsByClassName("radio1 radio2 radio3 radio4 radio5 radio6")
if (sequence === radio1 && sequence === radio2 && sequence === radio5) {
    window.location.href="test.html"    
}
else {
    alert("You put the sequence in incorrectly and have been destroyed!");
    window.location.href="index.html"   
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a demo here http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: The `onclick` attribute has to be a Javascript statement to execute. What do you expect `onclick='sequence'` to do? And how can the variable `sequence` be equal to 3 different things at the same time?

Comment: What you probably want each button's click handler to do is push its ID into an array. Then you can test whether the array contains the desired sequence.

Comment: @Barmar—sounds good, but I'd just create a string so `if (sequence == '125')`, or the OP might want `if (btn1.checked && btn2.checked && btn5.checked) destroyed = true;`. Also looks perfect for a map: `if (sequence == '11001')` or equivalent.

Comment: The string sounds good. The map might not be right -- I'm guessing he's doing something like Simon, where the order matters.